# How to read mdb from server (in sql)

Tags: sql-server

I have a server IP: 10.10.0.0 and in the Disk D I have a folder named "Export" and there I have my mdb file named BD2.mdb

In my laptop I want to insert in my mdb table all the rows from my sql table. My sql table "PERSON" have three fields: ID,Name,Age. My mdb file has a table name PERSON with the same fields as my sql table.

Finally in my sql server I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO OpenDataSource('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Data Source=\\10.10.0.0\Export\BD2.mdb')...PERSON(ID,Name,Age) 
select ID,Name,Age from PERSON
```

I mean: my mdb file is in server A. My sql database is in my laptop and i connect with the server writing \10.10.0.0\Export. I write this to tell you that the folder from the server is shared.

But i get this error:

```
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" Linked Server " (null) "Provider returned message " The engine of the database Microsoft Office Access can not open or write to file '\\10.10.0.0\Export\BD2.mdb'. This open exclusively by another user or search NEED YOUR permission to view or write data in the file." .
Msg 7303 , Level 16 , State 1 , Line 2
You Can not initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider " Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 " for linked server " ( null) " .
```

What can i do?

Comment: Have you verified that no other user has the MDB file open and the account under which SQL Server is running has the appropriate permissions on the file?

Comment: Yes. Im a little confuse, the mdb file is in the server. And my query is in my laptop when i run it doesnt work. But when run that query in sql that is in the server, it works, why?

Comment: Is there a difference between the account that runs SQL Server on your laptop and the SQL Server on the server?